# HTTPClient's PATCH method not allowing body entity?

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-patch

I am using Apache HTTPClient version 4.3.5.
I am trying to create a HTTP PATCH request.

```
HttpPatch request = new HttpPatch(ServerURL);
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(requestBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
request.setEntity(params);
client.execute(request);
```

On checking the actual request received, it didn't have a body associated with it.
Similar code is working fine for HTTP POST requests.

Comment: You can see exactly what kind of HTTP messages HttpClient generates by turning on wire logging as described here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html. I am quite sure HC can handle PATCH requests with content entity correctly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It was my mistake in some other part of the code. Once I fixed it, things started to work as expected.